# Why can't Pyglet draw a polygon correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyglet, opengl-compat

I'm randomly creating points to use to draw a polygon with Pyglet. But Pyglet doesn't do the job right most of the time.

Well I tried drawing a polygon with another graphic module and actually it worked but if Pyglet was working alright it would make my job easier.

I use this to draw polygon and points (to make it easy for you see).

```py
point_list = [18, 61, 59, 149, 328, 204, 305, 284, 3, 197, 25, 107]
ec = int(len(point_list)/2)
batch.add(ec, pyglet.gl.GL_POLYGON, None, ("v2i", point_list), ("c3B", [random.randrange(255)]*(3*ec)))
for i in range(int(len(point_list)/2)):
    p1 = point_list[i*2:2+i*2]
    p2 = point_list[2+i*2:4+i*2]

    if not len(p2):
        p2 = point_list[:2]

    batch.add(ec, pyglet.gl.GL_POINTS, None, ("v2i", point_list), ("c3B", [255]*(3*ec)))

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    batch.draw()
pyglet.app.run()
```

[image: actual result]

This is the result but it should be like the green colored polygon I drew below.
[image: wrong and correct]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PyGlet](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/programming_guide/graphics.html) is a OpenGL wrapper. Polygones which are drawn with the [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL) [Primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive) type `GL_POLYGON` have to be [Convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polygon). [Concave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_polygon) polygons might not be drawn correctly.

---

Use the primitive type [`GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives) and start with the point (59, 149). This will solve the issue in your special case:

```py
point_list = [59, 149, 328, 204, 305, 284, 3, 197, 25, 107, 18, 61]
ec = int(len(point_list)/2)
batch.add(ec, pyglet.gl.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, None, 
    ("v2i", point_list),
    ("c3B", [random.randrange(255)]*(3*ec)))
```

This causes this [Polygon triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation):

[image]

---

For any polygon you want to draw you've to find a proper [Polygon triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation). The triangulation can vary and one of the [Triangle primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives) types `GL_TRIANGLES`, `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` or `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` has to be used.

In some cases it is sufficient to change the start point of the polygon and to use the primitive type `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`.

e.g. the point list (from the commnet) `[488, 485, 375, 73, 61, 48, 70, 257, 119, 260, 418, 327]` can be change to `[375, 73, 61, 48, 70, 257, 119, 260, 418, 327, 488, 485]`:

[image]

---

For a more general approach you've to implement [Polygon triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation) algorithm like the [Two ears theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_ears_theorem), but OpenGL doesn't do the job for you.

Comment: It does work fot this exact point_list but with another it does not, why is that? For example: [488, 485, 375, 73, 61, 48, 70, 257, 119, 260, 418, 327]

Comment: @Adenzu It depends on the polygon and the [Polygon triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation). The triangulation depends on the [Triangle primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives) type. Even if you use `GL_POLYGON`, then the polygon is triangulated, but the exact triangulation is not specified and depends on the graphics hardware and driver.

Comment: One last thing. Do you happen to know a graphics library or a module for Python that can draw polygons with these kind of lists as I want to, even if numbers are random? Like being able to draw both the first and the second list correctly.