# Draw polygon with pyglet creates not wanted overlapping regions

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyglet, shapely

I am trying to draw a filled polygon with `pyglet` and I get overlapping regions where they are not wanted.

My (minimalist) code:

```
num_pts = 6 
pts_seq = [500, 129, 505, 92, 505, 114, 516, 114, 516, 93, 520, 129]
color= [255, 255, 200, 100]

pyglet.graphics.draw(
    num_pts,  # points count
    pyglet.gl.GL_POLYGON,  #
    ('v2i', pts_seq),  # data points
    ('c4B', color * num_pts),  # color data
)
```

Results:

[image]

I also tried the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57239633/why-cant-pyglet-draw-a-polygon-correctly) and got the same results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't Pyglet draw a polygon correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57239633/why-cant-pyglet-draw-a-polygon-correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyglet is based on OpenGL. The deprecated OpenGL [Primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive) type `GL_POLYGON` can only process convex  polygons correctly.
You have to triangulate the polygon and you have to use on of the [Triangle primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives) types `GL_TRIANGLES`, `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` or `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`.

For instance use the primitive type `GL_TRIANGLES`  and stitch together the shape through 4 triangles:

```py
num_pts = 12 
pts_seq = [
    500, 129, 505, 92, 505, 114,
    500, 129, 505, 114, 516, 114,
    500, 129, 516, 114, 520, 129,
    516, 114, 516, 93, 520, 129]
color= [255, 255, 200, 100]

pyglet.graphics.draw(
    num_pts,  # points count
    pyglet.gl.GL_TRIANGLES,  #
    ('v2i', pts_seq),  # data points
    ('c4B', color * num_pts),  # color data
)
```

Or change the order of the points and use the primitive type `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`:

```py
num_pts = 6
pts_seq = [505, 92, 500, 129, 505, 114, 520, 129, 516, 114, 516, 93]

color= [255, 255, 200, 100]

pyglet.graphics.draw(
    num_pts,  # points count
    pyglet.gl.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,  #
    ('v2i', pts_seq),  # data points
    ('c4B', color * num_pts),  # color data
)
```

Comment: Hi @Rabbid76, I like the second option using `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` because I would just need to sequence the points in the right order so that the merged triangles would make the polygon without ever overlapping with each other. But... is there any way to break the polygons down into the correct sequence of points automatically? I have many frames, each with a slight variation of the polygon shown (number and position of the points) in the original question, which eventually might contain a whole different shape already.

Comment: *"[...] is there any way to break the polygons down into the correct sequence of points automatically"* - No, not in OpenGL or pyglet. You have to implement an algorithm yourself. Search for "triangulation"

Answer (score 1):

@Rabbib76 answered this question and I would like to complete it with a strategy to triangulate the arbitrary polygons, which is no longer part of the original question, hence this post as an answer.

My solution has to do with the way the portion of code I am working on was developed, namely making use of `shapely`:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon as shPolygon
from shapely.ops import triangulate as shTriangulate

for pol_points in list_pol_points:
    obj_polygon = shPolygon(self.points)
    triangulated_objs = shTriangulate(obj_polygon)
    
    for sub_obj in triangulated_objs:
        if sub_obj.centroid.within(obj_polygon):
            sub_obj_points = list(sub_obj.exterior.coords)
            num_pts = len(sub_obj_points)
            pts_seq = []

            for point in sub_obj_points:
                pts_seq.append(point[0])
                pts_seq.append(point[1])

            pyglet.graphics.draw(
                num_pts,  # points count
                pyglet.gl.GL_POLYGON,  #
                ('v2i', pts_seq),  # data points
                ('c4B', color * num_pts),  # color data
            )
```